# Space below a canvas in a table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem in which an image or canvas with height `100%` in a table cell makes this cell grow.

Here's the whole page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table><tr><td id=t style="width:50px;height:50px;background:green;">
      <canvas id=c style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0"></canvas>
  </td></tr></table>
  <script>
    console.log($('#t').height());
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd expect to see `50` in the console but it logs `55`.

[This can be tested here](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/questionSOcell.html).

This page is the exact content of [a fiddle I had made on jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/adagit/3/edit), fiddle which logs the expected `50`.

Can somebody explain me what's exactly the difference and, more importantly, how to ensure my cell doesn't grow as it does, so that its height is 50 px just like its content, as is the case in jsbin ?

Comment: The "margin" is just the border-spacing inherited from the table, applied recursively. Now, why this is different in the jsbin and your example is beyond me. Although "5px" is also a mysterious value...

Comment: You are a horrible person.

Comment: I accept the first answer given because it solves the problem but any  explanation (that is a real one which would explain the 5px) would be welcomed with as many upvotes as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add in your canvas style

```
<canvas style="display:block"></canvas>
```

It only because the canvas have a default size bigger than expected.

Comment: It seems to work. So here's already a +1. But can you explain better why it works and why it works without it on jsbin.com ?

Comment: Note that it also works with this display style on the `td` element. Which doesn't make it clear yet...

Comment: And why exactly 5px ? In some of my tests, with my specific css, it was 4px... Where does this "margin" come from ?

Comment: The explanation is here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#attr-canvas-width

Comment: The issue is not with the Canvas but with the container it's in having `display: table-cell` by default. If you change the TD to block, or any other display type that meets your needs (aside from table-cell) it will not have the mystery padding/margin applied. I have tested this and inspected the crap out of all elements and I am sure this is the case; however looking at the specs there is no reason for this space to be added, and does not affect the other table display types (see table-row for example). [You can see it failing here as well but with a div](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/W73Ke/)